# Is there a way to rewrite this as a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have some repetitive code for finding direction in a game.  I think it should be written as a switch statement so it can run faster.  Is this possible?

```
    if (this.dw && !this.dd && !this.ds && !this.da) this.vector.angle = -90;
    else if (!this.dw && this.dd && !this.ds && !this.da) this.vector.angle = 0;
    else if (!this.dw && !this.dd && this.ds && !this.da) this.vector.angle = 90;
    else if (!this.dw && !this.dd && !this.ds && this.da) this.vector.angle = 180;
    else if (this.dw && this.dd && !this.ds && !this.da) this.vector.angle = -45;
    else if (!this.dw && this.dd && this.ds && !this.da) this.vector.angle = 45;
    else if (!this.dw && !this.dd && this.ds && this.da) this.vector.angle = 135;
    else if (this.dw && !this.dd && !this.ds && this.da) this.vector.angle = -135;
```

Comment: If you just want it to run faster, tree your `if`s

Comment: What are the meaning of dw, dd, ds and da?

Comment: @sturcotte06 is that even relevant to the question?

Comment: @sturcotte06 I'm assuming "direction" (d) and the keyboard keys w, a, s and d.

Comment: Yes, instead of booleans, populate the variables with directions (angle values), and do some calculations, you won't need `if`s at all.

Comment: that's not relevant? maybe there's a mathematical expression that can turn those ifs in a 1 liner.

Comment: Yeah they're just keyboard keys.  True is pressed, false is released

Comment: Not sure but why your if and else-if checking same condition again and again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just something like would do instead of a switch:

```
if (this.dd || this.dw || this.da || this.ds) {
    this.vector.angle = [ -135, -90, -45,
       180, 0, 0,
       135, 90, 45 ][(this.ds - this.dw + 1) * 3 + (this.dd - this.da + 1)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sideDirection = dd ? 1 : (da ? -1 : 0);
var frontDirection = dw ? 1 : (ds ? -1 : 0);
var direction = { sideDirection, frontDirection };

angleBetween(lastDirection, direction);
```

In your case, I think you want the angle relative to { 0, 1 } (top). So:

```
angleBetween({ 0, 1 }, direction);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have 2d array / vector:

```
var vector = [
    [ '-135',  '-90',  '-45'],
    [ 180,     null,   '0'  ],
    [ 135,     '90',   '45' ]
];
```

Then set the default centre point at 1, 1:

```
var cp = ['1', '1'];
```

Then move around the vector with this centre point variable, as in, if 'W' is pressed move up a row or if 'S' is pressed moved left one row. If both these keys are pressed, then you would move up a row and left one row and you would have selected '-135'.

So, to get the variable after a keypress event with this logic I would do:

```
var vector = [
    [ '-135', '-90', '-45' ],
    [ 180, null, '0' ],
    [ 135, '90', '45' ]
];

var cp = ['1', '1'];

this.dw && cp[1]--;
this.da && cp[0]--;
this.ds && cp[1]++;
this.dd && cp[0]++;

this.vector.angle = vector[ cp[0] ][ cp[1] ]
```

You could also set the vector variable globally, that's up to you. If this.vector.angle returns null then there has been no keypress so that's also a nice way to have a fallback for that case. This script also counts opposite keys out, so if 'A' and 'D' are pressed together then there is no horizontal movement in the vector.

P.S. I got slightly confused with your original angles, so wouldn't the vector variable really be something like this?:

```
var vector = [
    [ '315', '0', '45' ],
    [ 270, null, '90' ],
    [ 225, '180', '135' ]
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the question asked about `switch` (you can simplify the `parseInt`)

```
switch ((this.dw << 3) + (this.dd << 2) + (this.ds << 1) + this.da) {
    case parseInt('1000', 2): this.vector.angle =  -90; break;
    case parseInt('0100', 2): this.vector.angle =    0; break;
    case parseInt('0010', 2): this.vector.angle =   90; break;
    case parseInt('0001', 2): this.vector.angle =  180; break;
    case parseInt('1100', 2): this.vector.angle =  -45; break;
    case parseInt('0110', 2): this.vector.angle =   45; break;
    case parseInt('0011', 2): this.vector.angle =  135; break;
    case parseInt('1001', 2): this.vector.angle = -135; break;
}
```

You could simplify this again to an *Object* lookup, for example

```
this.vector.angle = {
    '1000':  -90,
    '0100':    0,
    '0010':   90,
    '0001':  180,
    '1100':  -45,
    '0110':   45,
    '0011':  135,
    '1001': -135,
}['' + (+this.dw) + (+this.dd) + (+this.ds) + (+this.da)];
```

I've just used binary-strings to make it easy to read, you may decide to do it all in *Int*